# What is the correct way to remove the revealed swipe of a UITableViewCell when using editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8

I have a `tableView` in which I am enabling swiping the cell  to reveal options - in my case, 'share' and 'delete' options by using the following method:

`- (NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{`

when a user swipes on a cell to reveal the options and then taps on `delete` I put up a `UIAlertController` with a confirmation. all is well and good if they say delete as i delete the object in my core data database  and my `NSFetchedResultController` takes care of updating the `tableView`

If the user declines to go through with the delete then the cell remains with the slide effect still revealing the options. I'd like it to go away. I know that `[tableView reloadData`] or, more efficiently, just reloading the one cell will solve the problem but is there a method call or property on the cell that I've missed that would do the job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you end editing on the table view here it will animate the cell back to its normal state.

```
- (NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [table setEditing:NO animated:YES];
}
```

If the table was in an editing state where it shows the delete button next to each cell, this will cause all of those delete buttons to go away, which may not be the behavior you want. In this case, you can immediately set the table view back to editing mode. The animation looks fine:

```
- (NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [table setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    if (yourWasPreviouslyEditingBoolean) {
        [table setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Note that you'll need to track this state yourself. Checking the table view's isEditing value will always return true here.

I haven't been able to find away to tell the cell directly to stop editing.

Answer (score 1):

So, your question is about how to reload one particular cell on a `UITableView`? Not hard.

The following code will do the trick:-

```
NSIndexPath * indexpath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.deletedTableRow
                                             inSection: self.deletedTableSection];
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexpath] 
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: cheers Ricky -Thanks for taking to the time to put that code snippet up - but that wasn't what i was looking for. I know how to reload a single cell.  What I was asking was is there a specific call on a cell that causes the revealed options to slide back out of view or was it just that you had to reload the cell to achieve that effect -which is what i had done. Thanks anyway

Comment: I think the answer is - you need to reload the cell!

Comment: @SimonTheDiver [tableView reloadData]  will reload the entire tableView which is not good if you have a lot of data. My solution above will only reload a single particular cell that you need to reload. About the animation and etc that you mentioned, it is all depends on your UITableViewCell/UITableView Delegates methods coding. You can even change a totally different UITableViewCell type with the above code.

Comment: Undrstood that Ricky. And, as I said above, I knew how to reload a single cell.   I didn't put the code in myself as it seemed unnecessary. The answer I was looking for was is there another way or is it a reload. If there isn't a specific method call available then reloading will be correct. I'll leave this a couple more days to see if anyone else has something to say before I mark your answer as correct if no other suggestion is put forward

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the same problem with putting a custom back button on the navbar. I had UITableViewController and UINavigationController. The "custom back button" action (implemented so) behaves like willDisappear.

Be careful for swipe "go back" gesture though.